# Jquery Static Menu to Wordpress Menu

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress, menu

Just a few days ago I got a great script which basically allows the menu items at my static site to shrink and expand depending on how many list items there was in the menu. Now I've started work on converting the site to a Wordpress installation and I'm having problems getting it to work because I'm not familiar with Javascript.

It won't run the script, just the basic Wordpress PHP.

This is the **script**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
  li_count = $('#main-navigation li').length;
  div_size = $('#main-navigation').width();
  new_li_font_size = (div_size/10)/li_count+'px';
new_li_width = 100/li_count+'%';
  $('#main-navigation li').css('font-size', new_li_font_size);
  $('#main-navigation li').css('width', new_li_width);
  console.debug(new_li_size);
});
```

This is my **previous nav**:

```
<nav id="main-navigation">
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Hjem</a></li>
    <li><a href="butikker-single.html">Butikker</a></li>
    <li><a href="kampanjer.html">Kampanjer</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Åpningstider</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Om torvgårdens ting og tang</a></li>
</ul>
</nav><!-- END #main-navigation -->
```

This is my **current nav**:

```
<nav id="main-navigation" role="navigation">
            <ul>
                <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu' ) ); ?>
            </ul>
        </nav><!-- END #main-navigation -->
```

I've been looking at the script and I think it could have something to do with the fact that there is no more li-tags in the php, but I might be wrong, considering I have no experience with jQuery. Is anyone able to help me out? :)

Just in case, here's the implementation of jQuery which I put in my head:

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/js/menu.js"></script>
```

Michael

Comment: Why don't you keep your parent wrapper's width `auto`,  without any fixed width?

Comment: @SheikHeera, I don't think the font-size would change as well if i did this. At some point with too many menu items the bar would overlap the set width, right?

Comment: What you are trying to do ?

Comment: I'd love to be able to use this script for the menu bar, that's all really. But it doesn't seem to register it anymore.

Comment: Do you want to add/register the script via WordPress hook to be used on `ready` event ?

Comment: Yes, definitly :) will it work even if the li's are gone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a script in `WordPress` you can use `wp_enqueue_script` in your `functions.php` file

```
function load_menu_js() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'menu_js',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/menu.js',
        array('jquery')
    );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_menu_js');
```

Above code will add the `script` in the head section of your page and you don't need to use `<script>` to add your `menu.js`tag manually and this is the recommended way.

Also you should use

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {      
        // code goes here
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Remove the script tag after the `wp_head()` you've used to load your `menu.js` file and also change the following code

```
<nav id="main-navigation" role="navigation">
        <ul>
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu' ) ); ?>
        </ul>
</nav>
```

to (`wp_nav_menu()` generates an `ul` filled with `li` tags)

```
<nav id="main-navigation" role="navigation">
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu' ) ); ?>
</nav>
```

Also remember `nav` is an `html5` tag, not supported in older browsers, you can use `<div id="main-navigation"></div>` instead.

Comment: Where should I use '(function ($) {' ? oh i should change that in the original script? Ill try it out, this looks great :)